# Show that if $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_{\phi(m)}$ is a reduced residue system modulo m, $m \neq 2$ then $c_1 + \cdots+ c_{\phi(m)} \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, symmetry

> Show that if $c_1, c_2,\ldots, c_{\phi(m)}$ is a reduced residue system modulo $m$, $m \neq 2$, and $m$ is a positive integer, then $c_1 +\cdots+ c_{\phi(m)} \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$

From the problem statement, I only know that $\gcd(c_i, m ) = 1$.
Is there any related theorem that I missed?

A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ It's a special case of Wilson's theorem for groups - see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/product-of-all-elements-in-an-odd-finite-abelian-group-is-1/9345#9345) - which highlights the key role played by symmetry (here a negation reflection / involution).

Said more simply, since your set is closed under the negation *reflection*, its non-fixed points $\rm -k\not\equiv k\:$ pair up and contribute zero to the sum, leaving only the sum of its fixed points $\rm - k\equiv k \iff 2k\equiv 0,\ $ so $\rm\ k\equiv 0\ $ if $\rm\: m\:$ is odd, else $\rm\ k \equiv 0,\ m/2$.

See also [Gauss's grade-school trick for summing an arithmetic progression.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242)

Comment: I will try to absorb this :(. Thank you.

Comment: @Chan: Please feel free to ask questions if anything is not clear. I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your nice offering! I really appreciated it. To be honest, sometimes I want to ask more, but I was not be able to understand it yet. So I could not even know how to ask. Sorry, I'm not a fast thinker, but I will try harder.

Comment: @Chan: It's always a good idea to say something about your background when asking a question, so that replies can be aimed at the appropriate level. Here it would be helpful to know if you know any group theory, or modular arithmetic (congruences), etc.

Comment: I will next time. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: If $c_i$ is a reduced residue class, then so is $m-c_i$. (Why?) and $\phi(m)$ is even $\forall m >2$

Comment: Ambikasaran: Thanks for a great hint.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $g.c.d(m-1,m) = 1$. Then $\{(m-1)c_{1},(m-1)c_{2},...,(m-1)c_{\phi(m)}\}$ are all relatively prime to m; furthermore, they are mutually incongruent, since $(m-1)c_{i} \equiv (m-1)c_{j} \ \ (mod \ m)$ implies that $c_{i} \equiv c_{j} \ \ (mod \ m)$, by the cancellation law. We may thus pair each $(m-1)c_{i}$ with some $c_{j}$ such that $(m-1)c_{i} \equiv c_{j} \ \ (mod \ m)$, and we note that $c_{j}$ is uniquely defined for each $(m-1)c_{i}$. Then $$(m-1) c_{i} + (m-1)c_{w} \equiv c_{j} + (m-1)c_{w} \ \ (mod \ m) \equiv c_{j} + c_{k} \ \ (mod \ m) $$. Then $$\sum_{l=1}^{\phi(m)} (m-1) c_{l} \equiv \sum_{l=1}^{\phi(m)} c_{l} \ \ (mod \ m)$$. This implie $$2\sum_{l=1}^{\phi(m)} c_{l} \equiv m\sum_{l=1}^{\phi(m)} c_{l}  \ \ (mod \ m) \equiv 0 \ \ (mod \ m)$$. If $g.c.d(2,m) = 1$, that is, m is odd, we have $$\sum_{l=1}^{\phi(m)} c_{l} \equiv 0 \ \ (mod \ m)$$.