# product of elements $\ne e$ implies only one element with order $2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group with even order and $M:=\{g\in G:g^2=e\}$.

It is easy to show that $M$ is a sugroup of $G$ and the number of elements of $M$ must be a power of $2$.

> I want to prove that the product of the elements of $G$ (which in this case is equal to the product of the elements of $M$) is not the identity element $e$, if and only if #$M=2$ (this means that there is only one element with order $2$). I found this claim when I studied the Wilson criterion for the primality of a number.

The case #$M=4$ is easy. If $a,b\in M$, we can show that $ab$ is not $a,b,e$, hence must be some other element $c$ and we get $abc=c^2=e$. But what about #$M=8$? If we have the elements $e,a,b,c,d,f,g,h$ and $ab=c$ and $df=g$, the product would be $h$ which is impossible considering my claim.

Who can complete my proof ?

Comment: I have seen this on MSE already. So far I only found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53185/the-product-of-all-the-elements-of-a-finite-abelian-group), but I will continue to search. I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474214/product-of-elements-of-a-finite-abelian-group), i.e., Wilson's theorem for finite abelian groups.

Comment: Peter, is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708979/how-to-determine-prod-g-in-gg-in-all-generality?noredirect=1&lq=1) not what you want?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your search, I will work throguh it.