# Product of all elements of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*, Chapter 2 has the following exercise:

> **1.8.** Let $G$ be a finite group, with exactly one element $f$ of order $2$. prove that $\prod_{g\in G} g = f$.

I can prove this if $G$ is abelian, but can't seem to prove it for the general case. (I think in the general case, the claim in the question is that the *any product* of all the group elements (irrespective of the order in which the elements appear in the product) equals $f$.)

On this site, I could find a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53185/673223) for the abelian case.

So, if the question is false, can someone confirm it by giving a **counterexample**?

Comment: This can't be right: if the product of all elements of a finite group doesn't depend on the order of those elements, one can prove immediately that the group is in fact abelian. The simplest nonabelian group I know with exactly one element of order 2 is $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times H$ where $H$ is the nonabelian group of order $21$; perhaps there's a counterexample there.

Comment: @GregMartin Perhaps a stupid question, but: in a nonabelian finite group $G$, can *every* $p\in G$ be written as a product of each element of $G$ exactly once?

Comment: Absent a specific order, the product does not determine a unique element if the group is nonabelian. The linked duplicate shows the assumption that $G$ is abelian is necessary not only for the result to hold, but to even make sense.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: no—in symmetric groups, for example, the parity of the product of all elements is independent of the order. More generally, if $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is abelian, the product of all elements of $G$ will be constrained by its image in $G/N$.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah, quite right, I *was* being silly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is proved here that you can obtain all elements in the relevant coset of $G'$: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808732572