# Product of invertibles in $\Bbb Z_n$ [Wilson's Theorem generalization]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can we compute the product of all invertibles in $\Bbb Z_n$?

In the special case $n=p$ where $p$ is a prime it is Wilson's theorem. By pairing inverses it reduces to computing the product of all $a$ such that $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}.\,$  How can we do that?

Comment: @mdave16 Yes of course.

Comment: Can you show that whatever the product is, its square must be $1$?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of group theory?  Where did you find the problem? (so we can surmise what level of math is expected)

Comment: @BillDubuque It was just asked by our teacher after wilson's theorem for research but I am a high school student and I don't have any knowledge of groupe theory.

Comment: @Taha I added a shorter proof to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most proofs use group theory. Since you don't know that, I will sketch a more elementary proof that attempts to expose some of the group-theoretic essence of the matter more simply.

As you noted, $ $ by pairing inverses the product reduces to the product of all roots of $\,x^2\!-\!1\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_n.\,$ If there is only one root $\,x = 1\,$ then the product  $= 1.\,$ Else there is a root $\,g\neq 1\,$ and using it we can *partition* the $k$ roots into *pairs* $(a,ga)$ since the map $\,a\mapsto ga$ is self inverse by $\,g^{-1}=g\,$ and $\,ga\neq a\,$ by $\,g\neq 1.\,$ Each pair $(a,ga)$ has product $a^2 g = g\,$ so the entire product $= g^{k/2}\! = g$ or $1,\,$ by $\,g^2 = 1.\,$ If there are exactly two roots $\,1,g\,$  then the product $= g.\,$ Else there is a third root $h$ and the same argument shows the entire product $= 1$ or $h,\,$ thus it must be $1,\,$ by $\,1,g,h\,$ distinct.

Using the above, we reduce to checking if the set of invertibles in $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ has at least two *nontrivial* roots $\,g,h\not\equiv 1$ of $\,x^2\equiv 1.\,$ For $n>2$ one nontrivial root is $\,h\equiv -1.\,$ The proof separates into a few cases, using nothing deeper than CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Let's do a typical case.

If $n$ is odd with at least two prime factors $\,p\neq q\,$ then $\,n = ab\,$ for coprime $a,b>2,\,$ so by CRT the solution of $\,g \equiv 1\pmod{\!a},\ g\equiv -1\pmod{\!b}\,$ satisfies $\,g^2\equiv 1,\,\ g\not\equiv -1,1\pmod{\!n}.\,$  Hence, by above, there are at least two nontrivial roots $\,g\,$ and $\, h\equiv -1\,$ so the product is $\,\equiv 1.\,$

The few remaining cases can be dispatched in similarly simple ways, e.g. see Theorem $2.2$ in [Wilson's Theorem: an algebraic approach](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/wilson_easy.pdf) by Pete L. Clark.

**Remark** $ $ Here is another elementary way to compute the root product. If there are at least two nontrivial roots $\,g,h\not\equiv 1.\,$ We show that the product of all roots is $\equiv 1$ by placing them into *quads* (vs pairs) with product $1$. Define $\,a\sim b$ if $a$ can be obtained from $b$ by a sequence of "reflections" of the form $\,x\mapsto gx\,$ or $\,x\mapsto hx\,$ or, equivalently, if $\, a = g^i h^j b\,$ for some integers $i,j$.

It is [easy to check](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3286850/242) that this is an *equivalence relation*, so it partitions the roots into disjoint classes of equivalent elements. Further, since $\,g^2\equiv 1\equiv h^2$ it is easy to show that each equivalence class has exactly $4$ elements of form $\, \{a, ga, ha, gha\}\,$ with product $\,(a^2 gh)^2 \equiv 1.\,$ Thus the product of all roots partitions into a product of quads with product $1$, so the entire product is also $\,\equiv 1.$

If you learn group theory it is enlightening to revisit the above proof to see how it is used implicitly above. The pairs are the cosets $aG$ of the subgroup $G = \left<g\right> = \{1,g\}$ and the quads are the cosets $aG$ of the subgroup $\,G = \left<g,h\right> = \{1,g,h,gh\}$ or, equivalently, the orbits of $a$ under $G$, so we are essentially repeating a (special-case) proof of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

You can find links to other classical approaches in the above linked paper. Exploiting innate reflection (involution) symmetry (as in the pairing and quading above) [is a widely applicable method](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+involution) that often leads to elegant proofs.

The ideas above generalize Wilson's theorem even further to: if a finite abelian group has a unique element of order $2$ then it equals the product of all the elements; otherwise the product is $1$. You can find another classical proof of this in Pete L. Clark's notes listed above

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122072/242) is a similar classical proof that $-1$ is a square in a finite field of odd size $\,q\iff q\equiv1\pmod{\!4}$ $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 4):

[Gauss's generalization of Wilson's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonsTheorem.html).  The product is $-1$ mod $n$ if $n$ is $4$, a power of an odd prime, or twice a power of an odd prime; for all other $n>1$ it is $1$.  See also [OEIS sequence A001783](http://oeis.org/A001783).

Comment: Could you give a link to its proof?

Comment: I mean the part for all other $n>1$?The other parts can be proved easily.

Comment: @Taha I added a sketch of an elementary proof avoiding group theory.