# Equation : $x^2+1\equiv 0\mod {p}$. admits only two solutions if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need help on how to prove that this equation $x^2+1\equiv 0\mod {p}$ ;where p is a prime number, admits only two solutions if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$?

Comment: What do you know about the number of zeros a polynomial of degree $n$ can have in a field?

Comment: Also, I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). If you do, you will have a smoother ride here!

Comment: a polynomial of degree n over a field has at most n roots.

Comment: Correct! $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is a field, so...?

Comment: so for our case the polynome of degree 2 has at most 2 roots in this field.

Comment: Correct, again. Well done! The (IMHO) harder direction is to prove that this particular quadratic has those two solutions, when $p\equiv1\pmod4$. However, that has been discussed on our site many times already.

Comment: Thanks Doctor for the hints, they are indeed helpful. would you please direct me to any link in the website where this issue is discussed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for every $a\neq0\pmod p$, there is a $b=1/a$ for which $ab=1\pmod p$.
Group the numbers from $2$ to $p-2$ into quartets $\{a,-a,1/a,-1/a\}$.
There are $p-3$ numbers involved, so two numbers must be left over.  That is because two of the four numbers are the same.  You can't have $a=-a$ since $a\ne0$, and you can't have $a=1/a$ since $a$ is neither $1$ nor $p-1$, so you must have $a=-1/a$, or $a^2+1=0$.

Comment: For more on this [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122072/242) and see the posts I linked in the comment (and its coments links ...)  And compare to the [Remark here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372358/242)