# Product of elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>1$. Let $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ be the Multiplicative group of primitive residue classes modulo $n$. By Wilson's theorem, it's clear that
$$\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k=-1$$
if $n$ is prime. Also, for all $n$, we can say that
$$\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k^2=1$$
since $\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k=\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k^{-1}$. How can I find the product $\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k$ if $n$ is not a prime ? Is there a generalization for the **Wilson's theorem** ?

It's clear that $\text{ord}(\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k)$ is $1$ or $2$ since $(\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}k)^2=1$.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/prove-that-the-product-of-coprimes-must-be-congruent-to-1-or-1-pmodm answer your question?

Comment: @Arthur No, I want in which cases that the product is $-1$ and when the product is not $-1$, and how to prove it using Group Theory

Comment: A group-theoretic idea is also mentioned in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474536/450991

Comment: google "generalized wilson theorem" gives you results of that kind.

Comment: @CadeReinberger thank you! It is usefull

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization

Comment: As the product of a value, and the additive inverse of it's multiplicative inverse is $-1$ we can group in pairs of pairings to get $1$ so it depends on $\phi(n)$ modulo $4$ etc.

Comment: Only exceptions would be things like mod 5, where $-(2^{-1})\equiv 2$