# Solve $\frac{1}{2} n \varphi(n) \bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

How can I solve the equation
\begin{align*}
(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{\varphi(n)}) \bmod n,
\end{align*}
where $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{\varphi(n)}$ are the positive numbers relatively prime to $n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$), and smaller than $n$. I know that you can write this sum on the form
\begin{align*}
(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{\varphi(n)}) = \frac{1}{2} n \varphi(n)
\end{align*}
and thus the equation simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} n \varphi(n) \bmod n
\end{align*}
I know that $n \bmod n = 0$. Does this mean that also $\frac{1}{2} n \varphi(n) \bmod n = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that the [Euler Totient function is always even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702550/why-is-eulers-totient-function-always-even) for $n \ge 3$, so we must have that $\frac{\phi(n)}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$, so therefore we have that $\frac 12 \phi(n)n$ is a mulitple of $n$.