# What is the value of $ \ n\ $ such that $\ \xi_{n}= e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}} \ $

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

What is the value of $ \ n\ $ such that $\ \xi_{n}= e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}} \ $  has degree at most  $ \ 3 \ $    i.e, $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\xi) : \mathbb{Q}]=3 $ . $$ $$ I have thought that - since $ [\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{n}) : \mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n) $ , we have $ \ \phi(n)=3 $ . Or , **n= ? . please help me .**

Comment: Last time I checked $\Bbb{Q}$ had infinitely many elements, so I removed the tag [tag:finite-fields].

Comment: why to make negative grade

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question asks for degree *at most* 3. So possible answers include $n=2,3$. Also, notice that $\phi(n)$ is even for $n\ge 3$ (see here [Why is Euler's Totient function always even?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702550/why-is-eulers-totient-function-always-even)) so you cannot get exact equality.

Comment: Also n may be 4,6 because $ \phi(n)=2 \ \ implies \ \ n=4,6,3 $

Comment: 4,6 are fine as well. It was not meant to be an exhaustive list