# Which of the following statements are true? number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

For a positive integer N, let φ(N) denote the number of positive integers
(including unity) which are less than N and coprime to it. Which of the
following statements are true?

a. If N is not equal to M then φ(NM) = φ(N)φ(M).

b. If N > 2, then φ(N) is always even

c. If p is a prime and if N = p^k , k ∈ N, then φ(N) = N(1-1/p)

i think all option a) and C)  are correct according to euler theorem..

But still im doubting about my answer.
If  anybody body help me i would be very thankful to him..

Comment: Which Euler theorem do you mean (there are something like a million of them). Did you try to compute some small examples?

Comment: What happened when you tested these three statements by plugging in various values of $N$ and $M$?

Answer (score 0):

a) is true only if $N$ and $M$ are coprime - i.e. $\phi$ is multiplicative, but *not* completely multiplicative

b) Edit: True!

c) True! $\phi(p) = p-1$ for prime $p$, and there are $p^{k-1}$ integers, $n$ such that $1 \leq n leq p^{k}$ which are divisible by $p$. Combine these facts :)

EDIT: to prove a) for coprime $N$ and $M$, consider the sets $A,B,C$ which are less than and coprime to $N$, $M$ and $NM$ resp. Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is a bijection between $A \times B$ and $C$

Comment: Actually b) is true. $\varphi(4) = 2$.

Comment: thanks a lot  @ THe mathsGeek ,,,but im not getting opt b)

Comment: You're right! Read the question the wrong way around!

Comment: @legoh legoh my apologies, I read the question incorrectly first time around. b) is true (and is in fact answered in this post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702550/why-is-eulers-totient-function-always-even)