# Sum of elements in reduced residue system modulo n is divisible by n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reduced-residue-system

Prove that sum of elements in reduced residue system modulo $n \in N$ is divisible by $n$.

I feel like problem just comes down to pairing elements of RRS in way that they are congruent, but can't quite work it out.
Please post detailed and readable answer, as most of problems I need to do basically comes down to this one ..

Comment: Not true for even $n$.

Comment: Really ? What's your counterexample ?

Comment: @someone what about $2$?

Comment: @MagedSaeed Is it working for $n \ne 2$ ?

Comment: @someone consider my answer for other values of $n$. :)

Comment: @MagedSaeed Should I delete this question then ?

Comment: I kind of feel that the accepted answer in that post is more math involved. If you feel the answer and hints provided there are sufficient, then you may delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduced residue system of $2$ is only $1$. But $2\not | 1$, so, $n > 2$.

Let us address this problem for numbers greater than $2$. Now, since $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, what can you say about $\gcd(n-a,n)$? It is also $1$. Now, we can use this to pair elements of the Reduced Residue System, as you have suggested, as follows:

$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{\phi(n)\over2}+(n-a_1)+(n-a_2)+\cdots+(n-a_{\phi(n)\over2}) = \frac{\phi(n)}{2}n$. This also can give you a hint why $2$ is a counter example as $\phi(n)$ is only odd for $n=2$. This answer is collected from answers in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23924/show-that-if-c-1-c-2-ldots-c-phim-is-a-reduced-residue-system-modulo).

Comment: Ooh, right .. So if $k \in RRS$ then $n-k \in RRS$ because $(n-k, n) = 1$ and $n-k \ne k 
 mod n$ ?

Comment: Yeah, you got it.