# Sum of elements of a set where $\gcd(p,q)=1$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a formula for the sum of the elements of the set $N(q) =
\{p \mid \gcd(p,q)=1, p < q\}$ ?

Comment: When $q$ is a prime, yes :) then it would be $$\frac{q(q-1)}{2}.$$ In general, I don't know, so I will leave that to someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: @Andreas: Actually `\gcd` is a native MathJax (and LaTeX) operator. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that was absent minded of me, fixed, thanks. (The point being that I usually write it as $(a, b)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know there are $\phi(q)$ positive integers $a<q$ such that $(a,q)=1$

where $\phi(q)$  [Euler's totient function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html)

For $q\ge3$ we know $\phi(q)$ is [even](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler_Phi_Function_Even_for_Argument_Greater_than_2).

If $1\le a\le \lfloor \frac q2\rfloor$ and $(a,q)=1$

$(q-a,q)=(a,q)=1$

So, we have $\frac{\phi(q)}2$ pairs of numbers $a$ and $q-a$ whose sum is $q$

So, the sum will be $\frac{q\phi(q)}2$ for $q\ge3$

Comment: Just found http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Famous_Theorems_of_Mathematics/Number_Theory/Totient_Function

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Use [Gauss's famous grade-school trick,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7077/23500) pairing up terms around the center, noting that $\rm\: (k,q)\equiv 1\iff (q\!-\!k,q) = 1,\:$  omitting $\rm\color{tan}{terms}$ not comprime to $\rm\,q,\:$ e.g. for $\rm\,q=15$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 1 & 2 & \color{tan}3 & 4 & \color{tan}5 & \color{tan}6 & 7 \\
14 & 13 & \color{tan}{12} & 11 & \color{tan}{10} & \color{tan}9 & 8 \\ 
\hline
15 & 15 &  & 15 & & & 15
\end{array} \\
\rm\ \  sum\, =\, 15\cdot 4\, =\, 15\cdot \phi(15)/2 
\end{array}$$

**Remark** $\ $ This trick of pairing up reflections around the average value is a special case of exploiting innate symmetry - here a reflection or involution. Here we  essentially exploit the reflection symmetry arising from *negation* $\rm\ k\to -k\equiv q\!-\!k\,\ (mod\ q),\:$ after noting that the reflection restricts to units (invertibles) $\rm\:mod\ q.\:$ Such symmetry applications are ubiquitous in number theory and algebra, e.g. see these posts on [Wilson's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865) and its [group theoretic generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/product-of-all-elements-in-an-odd-finite-abelian-group-is-1/9345#9345).