# Remainder question with $6!$ and 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find the remainder when $6!$ is divided by 7.

I know that you can answer this question by computing $6! = 720$ and then using short division, but is there a way to find the remainder without using short division?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $7$ is prime, use [Wilson's Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_Theorem)  $$(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$$ for prime  $p$

Now, $\displaystyle -1\equiv p-1\pmod p$

Comment: clean, concise, and uses a nice theorem +1

Comment: What does this exactly mean? Sorry I am not an expert in maths.

Comment: @user108104 In my answer, I have specialized a proof of Wilson's Theorem to your specific case. I think you will find it quite intuitive in this concrete instance.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ In analogy with **Gauss's trick** (see below), to simplify the product we pair up each number with its (multiplicative) inverse mod $7.\,$ Thus $$ 6! = 1\cdot (\overbrace{2\cdot 4}^{\equiv \,1})(\overbrace{3\cdot5}^{\equiv\, 1})\cdot 6 \equiv 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 6\equiv6\pmod{7}$$

**Remark** $\ $ This method of pairing up inverses works for any prime - see [Wilson's Theorem.](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_Theorem)

Below is **Gauss's trick**, imported from [a deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7077/242)

$\qquad\qquad \begin{array}{rcl}\rm{\bf Hint}\quad\quad\ \ S &=&\rm 1 \ \ \ +\ \ \: 2\ \ \ \ +\ \:\cdots\  +\ n\!-\!1\ +\ n \\  
\rm S &=&\rm n \ \ +\   n\!-\!1\ +\,\ \cdots\ +\,\quad 2\ \ \ +\ \ 1\\
\hline \\
\rm Adding\ \ \ \ 2\: S &=&\rm n\ (n\!+\!1)\end{array}$

A [famous legend](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/gausss-day-of-reckoning) says Gauss used this trick to quickly compute $ 1+2+\:\cdots\:+100\ $ in grade school.

This trick of pairing up reflections around the average value is a special case of exploiting innate symmetry - here a reflection or involution. It's a ubiquitous powerful technique, e.g. see my post on [Wilson's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865) and it's [group theoretic generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/product-of-all-elements-in-an-odd-finite-abelian-group-is-1/9345#9345).