# Without using Lagrange's theorem, show that an abelian group of odd order cannot have an element of even order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G $ be an abelian group of odd order, say $n$. Then, by fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $G$ is a direct product of groups of prime power order.
Let
$$ G=\mathbb Z_{{p_1}^{n_1}} \oplus \mathbb Z_{{p_2}^{n_2}}\oplus \cdots\oplus\mathbb Z_{{p_k}^{n_k}}.$$
Then $\vert G\vert=n={p_1}^{n_1}{p_2}^{n_2}\cdots{p_k}^{n_k}$. Now let $(g_1,g_2,...,g_k)\in G$. Then $\vert (g_1,g_2,...,g_k
)\vert=\mathrm{lcm}(\vert g_1 \vert,\vert g_2 \vert,...,\vert g_k \vert)$.

From here how to move, i don't know but it is given in the hint to make use of *fundamental theorem of cyclic groups* (but i'm not getting how to apply it here).

Comment: How do you get the decomposition into a direct sum of cyclic groups without Lagrange theorem?

Comment: @egreg:Since G is abelian,then by fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups(which states that-every finite abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order) it can be represented as the direct product of cyclic groups.

Comment: The point is that it does not make any sense to avoid using Lagrange's Theorem if you are going to use a more advanced theorem like the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can prove the fundamental theorem without using Lagrange (which I don't believe), a consequence of the theorem is that, for every $x\in G$, $x^n=1$, because $n$ is a multiple of the order of every cyclic component and, clearly, in a cyclic group $C$ of order $k$, we have $g^k=1$, for every $c\in C$.

The map $x\mapsto x^2$ is an endomorphism of $G$ and, since $n=2k+1$ is odd, we have
$$
x=(x^{k+1})^2
$$
so the map is surjective. Thus the map is also injective, therefore $x^2=1$ implies $x=1$ and there's no element of order $2$.

Comment: :I did'nt noticed this fact that proof of FTFAG makes use of Lagrange's theorem.But this exercise is from Gallian's algebra text.Whatever i mentioned in my post is directed through the hint in the very text.May be i'm wrong in understanding the hint.Hints are given as-use 1.Fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.2.Order of elements in a direct product.3.Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups  .

Comment: @PKStyles That's what I used

Comment: :How does $x=(x^{k+1})^2$ happen?

Comment: @PKStyles Since $n=2k+1$, $(x^{k+1})^2=x^{2k+2}=x^{n+1}=x^nx=x$

Comment: :thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $g\in G$ has even order, say $2m$, then $g^m$ has order $2$ so assume $g$ has order $2$, then we can partition $G$ into pairs, $\{h,k\}$ where $h=gk$ and $k=gh$.

This is of course impossible since $G$ has odd order, so we have the result by contradiction.

Comment: Nice. This works even if $G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [egreg](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949502) that using the FTFGAG seems very much like overkill; and [Robert Chamberlain](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949587)'s proof is very nice, but seems essentially to be re-proving Lagrange's theorem in this case.  I wonder whether what Gallian has in mind isn't just to use the fact that [multiplication by $g^n$ fixes the product of the elements of $G$, hence is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654641/if-g-g-1-g-2-g-n-is-a-finite-abelian-group-then-for-any-x-in); so, if $g$ had even order $m$, then we would have that there existed integers $a$ and $b$ so that $g^{\gcd(m, n)} = g^{a m + b n} = (g^m)^a(g^n)^b = 1$.  This is a contradiction, since $\gcd(m, n)$ is positive but strictly less than $m$ (it divides $m$, and is odd so it divides $n$, so it doesn't equal $m$).